# Add a checkbox in the admin product page (Prestashop)

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I have created a module to add different fields in the admin of the product sheet and I have a registration problem for the checkboxes my other input works very well. I don't see where the problem is coming from. Here is my product class:

```
<?php

class Product extends ProductCore
{
    public $solde_display;
    public $only_marketplace;
    public $on_vp;
    public $boost_product;
    public $price_market;
    public $tagmodele;

    public function __construct($id_product = null, $full = false, $id_lang = null, $id_shop = null, Context $context = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($id_product, $full, $id_lang, $id_shop, $context);

        // Boolean
        self::$definition['fields']['solde_display'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL);
        self::$definition['fields']['only_marketplace'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL);
        self::$definition['fields']['on_vp'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL);
        self::$definition['fields']['boost_product'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL);

        // Text
        self::$definition['fields']['price_market'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_FLOAT, 'validate' => 'isPrice');
        self::$definition['fields']['tagmodele'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING);

    }
}
```

My template:

```
    <div class="m-b-1 m-t-1">
    <h2>{l s='Champs supplémentaires (Générale)' mod='overrideoptions'}</h2>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-xl-5">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label for="on_vp">
                <input type="checkbox" name="on_vp" id="on_vp" value="1" {if $on_vp}checked="checked"{/if}>
                    Produit en Vente Privée
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-xl-5">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label for="solde_display">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="solde_display" id="solde_display" value="1" {if $solde_display}checked="checked"{/if}>
                    Solde display
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-xl-5">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label for="only_marketplace">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="only_marketplace" id="only_marketplace" value="1" {if $only_marketplace}checked="checked"{/if}>
                    Disponible uniquement en Place de marché !
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-xl-5">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label for="boost_product">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="boost_product" id="boost_product" value="1" {if $boost_product}checked="checked"{/if}>
                    Boost Product (Google Shopping)
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="tagmodele">Tag modele</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tagmodele" id="tagmodele" placeholder="Tag modele" value="{$tagmodele}">
    </div>
</div>
```

the Tag model registers very well except the checkbox.

Thanks for your help

Comment: any idea for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late but if it can help someone else...

You need to override the following file `override/controllers/admin/AdminProductsController.php` and add the logic to save your checkboxes such as

```
class AdminProductsController extends AdminProductsControllerCore
{

    protected function copyFromPost(&$object, $table)
    {
        parent::copyFromPost($object, $table);
        $object->solde_display = (int)Tools::getValue('solde_display');
        $object->only_marketplace = (int)Tools::getValue('only_marketplace');
        [...]
    }
}
```